# How to remove browser name from titlebar

Tags: titlebar

I need to remove Mozilla Firefox / Google Chrome which comes at the end of title of my website.For Example : music.Google.com  website  in which  browser name is not available after title name. I tried

```
document.title="ABC";
```

So I want only ABC in my title bar. But, currently it shows

```
ABC -Google Chrome
```

and in firefox

```
ABC- MOZILLA Firefox
```

Comment: Can you post the `<head>` section of your html?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible in HTML or Javascript for any browser. There are extensions for Firefox that allow the user to customise the title bar. I don't know about Chrome.

Comment: To get the attention of users able to answer this question, you should [edit] it and add tags to indicate the applicable languages. Though Mike is probably right.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible for a page to change. Browsers add this text after whatever title the page sets.

Answer (score 0):

The universal solution is to use your OS to change the titles of windows. On Linux (Debian) I remove the browser name from the window title using [wmctrl](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) and a simple script that goes over all window titles every second and modifies them.

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

function remove_chrome_suffix {
    WINDOWS=$(wmctrl -l | grep " - Google Chrome$")
    IFS=$'\n'
    for W in $WINDOWS; do
        CMD="wmctrl -i -r "$(echo "$W" | grep -o "^[^ ]\+")" "
        CMD=$(printf "%s-T %q" $CMD $(echo "$W" | grep -oP "^[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +\\K.*(?= - Google Chrome$)"))
        eval "$CMD"
    done
    unset IFS
}

while true; do
    remove_chrome_suffix
    sleep 1
done
```

I launch it as follows:

```
nohup <script file> &>/dev/null &
```